# DSP Practicals - Hands on learning

Tags: signal-processing

My first feeling after reading - DSP for beginners, is that if I can do some practicals I would understand it much better. I have never seen a signal and how FIR / IIR filters to an input signal would modify it. In other words is there a DSP software that would teach me DSP practically?

I can understand what the book is talking about but I am not getting how it works or what / when it is used for. If I can get any tool that demonstrate DSP practically it would be best for my training. I have heard of "Bloom with DSP" training software - but I could not locate it in net. Is there any thing available of the type I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best books I've read on DSP is: "Software Receiver Design: Build Your Own Digital Communication System in Five Easy Steps."

You can find it for a fairly low price on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521189446)!

It has hundreds of exercises in both C and MATLAB that allow for readers to work on problems associated with topics discussed in the text.

It briefly discusses the theory behind topics, but then goes deeper into practical uses and design of DSP concepts - which sounds like that's what you're looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks much for the book details. Are there any such other books also available . Please let me know other books details - in word I can say that currently they are oxygen for me. I have placed an order for the above mentioned book. Thanks once again. Please provide the requested details

Answer (score 2):

You could try Pure Data. It's a free opensource audio/visual programming language, where you do things by patching low level building blocks. And it's realtime. No recompiling or anything. You can change the parameters or code/structure anytime and hear/see the difference instantly. Except for routing the output of filter into your soundcard, there are also some scope objects, which you can use. Also an FFT object if you want to analyze the spectrum. In my opinion it's better for your purpose than C as (with some practice) you can build things there very quickly and you don't have to recompile with every change you make.

Comment: Thanks I installed it from http://puredata.info/docs/faq/debian on my Ubuntu box. Is there a tutorial for beginners plus sample / code which I can refer to understand DSP and functionalities of Pure Data. Note the links in https://puredata.info/docs/tutorials are broken at least specific to FFT and a few others

Comment: There are good tutorials included in the ./doc subdirectory. Most of them are not in text format, but as pure data patches. I was learning from that. You can even jump directly to ./doc/3.audio.examples to the topic of your interest, but it's perhaps better to learn the basics first, so that you'll be able to adjust the tutorial patches to your needs (adding scopes/analyzers...). I also have to say that learning this way is a lot of fun. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the best ways to learn DSP is to go the audio route, wherein signals can be both visualized and heard. As Angakok mentioned, Pure Data can be a good resource. A better, updated way is using Max/MSP - in which there are different DSP function blocks with can be easily hooked up to both audio output and graphs/visualizers.

If you want to go the more analytical route of understanding MATLAB/Simulink is probably better. A vast array of resources are available for DSP with MATLAB - such as https://www.mathworks.com/solutions/dsp.html, etc. A quick google search will also get you to a bunch of books directly related to that.

Adding to that, try out - https://ccrma.stanford.edu/. Prof. Julius does a great job at explaining analytically a lot of DSP algorithms, geared towards Audio - with MATLAB code snippets.

Several online/web-based tools such as https://dspfirst.gatech.edu/, https://www.minidsp.com/applications/advanced-tools/rephase-fir-tool etc. can also be used.